Replace a static build of data with a dynamic way
I'm trying to replace a static way of getting data for a custom SQL by a dynamic way.
$filter1 = array( array('id' => 101, 'field' => 'name', 'name' => 'John'),
                  array('id' => 102, 'field' => 'name', 'name' => 'Mary'));

$custom_fields_array['Name_of_filter_1'] = $filter1;

$filter2 = array( array('id' => 201, 'field' => 'number', 'name' => '1234'),
                  array('id' => 202, 'field' => 'number', 'name' => '4321'));

$custom_fields_array['Name_of_filter_2'] = $filter2;    

foreach($custom_fields_array as $block_name => $block_array) {  
  if($block_array <> NULL) {
    foreach($block_array as $bf_array) {
      if(!empty($get_custom_fields) and in_array($bf_array['id'],$get_custom_fields)) {
        if ($bf_array['id'] == 101) {
          $custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "John" ';
        } else if ($bf_array['id'] == 102) {
          $custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "Mary" ';
        } else if ($bf_array['id'] == 201) {
          $custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "1234" ';
        } else if ($bf_array['id'] == 202) {
          $custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "4321" ';
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}

Now the first thing I replaced ($filter1) works:
$cs_dl_query = mysqli_query("SELECT name FROM customers");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($cs_dl_query)) { 
    $item = 100;
      while($res_cs_dl = mysqli_fetch_array($cs_dl_query)){
        $item++;
        $cs_dl_array[] = array('id' => $item, 'field' => 'name', 'name' => $res_cs_dl['name']);
      }
  }
$filter1 = $cs_dl_array;

$cs_dl2_query = mysqli_query("SELECT number FROM customers");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($cs_dl2_query)) { 
    $item = 200;
      while($res_cs2_dl = mysqli_fetch_array($cs_dl2_query)){
        $item++;
        $cs_dl2_array[] = array('id' => $item, 'field' => 'number', 'name' => $res_cs2_dl['number']);
      }
  }
$filter2 = $cs_dl2_array;    

The problem is to prepare the if statements in the foreach block with the data collected for $filter1
I've tried to add it to a string and add the string in between the other if statements, but that just gives errors.
Any advice how I could dynamically create this:
if ($bf_array['id'] == 101) {
  $custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "John" ';
} else if ($bf_array['id'] == 102) {
  $custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "Mary" ';
} else if ($bf_array['id'] == 202) {
  $custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "1234" ';
} else if ($bf_array['id'] == 202) {
  $custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "4321" ';
}

With the pointers of IT goldman, this is what solved it.
  foreach($custom_fields_array as $block_name => $block_array) {  
    if($block_array <> NULL) {
      foreach($block_array as $bf_array) {
        if(!empty($get_custom_fields) and in_array($bf_array['id'],$get_custom_fields)) {
          foreach ($bf_array as $name_of_filter => $filter) {
            if ($filter == $bf_array['id']) {
              $custom_fields[] = 'pf.' . $bf_array['field'] . ' = "' . $bf_array['name'] . '" ';
            }
          }
          }
        }  
      }
    }
  }

This results in this being created:
$custom_fields[] = 'pf.'.$bf_array['field'].' = "Mary" ';


The first code section, the 'static way' is not complete. What is $get_custom_fields for example? It should be code which we can run. In addition you haven't posted the result of that code.

@Gian no one should be doing what you are doing.  You are performing the bad practice of injecting variables into an SQL query.  You need to educate yourself on the importance of using prepared statements.

This whole task is almost certainly an XY Problem.  You are pulling data out of your database, manipulating it, then feeding it back into your database?  Also, your queries to pull data out are not explicitly using ORDER BY, but you are incrementing the id values as if they are guaranteed to be in the same order each time your code runs -- this is not guaranteed by the database.  You should be setting exact id values for customers names -- if they need to start at 100, design a TRIGGER to auto-populate the next numeric value; same with customers numbers starting at 200.

Overall, I reckon some serious database re-design might be in order.  Do you even have a primary key in the customers table?

From what I understand you're basically want to find an item in array by a key?
By the way, if all of these are going into a SQL query, pay attention not to be vulnerable to SQL injection, if one of the values contains '
foreach ($custom_fields_array as $block_name => $block_array) {
    if ($block_array <> NULL) {
        foreach ($block_array as $bf_array) {
            if (!empty($get_custom_fields) and in_array($bf_array['id'], $get_custom_fields)) {
                $found = null;
                // find item in filter1 by $bf_array['id']
                foreach ($filter1 as $filter) {
                    if ($filter['id'] == $bf_array['id']) {
                        $found = $filter;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ($found) {
                    $custom_fields[] = 'pf.' . $bf_array['field'] . ' = "' . $found['name'] . '" ';
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

Attempt 2:
Create an array of filters. So you can iterate them.
$custom_fields_array['Name_of_filter_1'] = $filter1;
$custom_fields_array['Name_of_filter_2'] = $filter2;

foreach ($custom_fields_array as $block_name => $block_array) {
    if ($block_array <> NULL) {
        foreach ($block_array as $bf_array) {
            if (!empty($get_custom_fields) and in_array($bf_array['id'], $get_custom_fields)) {

                $found = null;
                foreach ($custom_fields as $name_of_filter => $filter) {
                    foreach ($filter as $item) {
                        if ($item['id'] == $bf_array['id']) {
                            $found = $item;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($found) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ($found) {
                    $custom_fields[] = 'pf.' . $found['field'] . ' = "' . $found['name'] . '" ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Hi IT goldman, I've corrected the question, it might have been cutting corners in the question.
I need to get all the entries for that specific filter replaced by a dynamic way.
And there are more filters, it will actually start at 20 filters, each can hold 2 till 100 entries per filter

i've updated my answer

WIth a little tweak, I've come to a solution thanks your pointers, thank you very much.
The next thing is to make this multilingual, but I've almost finished that part too thanks this this help

I don't know exactly what you are doing AND it doesn't look like good practice, but if you want to search for data based on your generated numeric values, create a lookup array with those numbers as keys.
$lookup = [];
foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT name, number FROM customers') as $i => ['name' => $name, 'number' => $number]) {
    $lookup[$i + 100] = ['name', $name];
    $lookup[$i + 200] = ['number', $number];
}

$custom_fields = [];
foreach ($custom_fields_array as $block_array) {  
    foreach ($block_array ?? [] as $bf_array) {
        if (isset($lookup[$bf_array['id']])) {
            $custom_fields[] = vsprintf('pf.%s = "%s"', $lookup[$bf_array['id']]);
        }
    }
}

This is far more tidy.    ...but I these stored "expressions" shouldn't be used to query the database.  Prepared statements need to be implemented -- the adjustment isn't hard...
$custom_fields = [];
$paramters = [];
foreach ($custom_fields_array as $block_array) {  
    foreach ($block_array ?? [] as $bf_array) {
        if (isset($lookup[$bf_array['id']])) {
            $custom_fields[] = sprintf('pf.%s = ?', $lookup[$bf_array['id']][0]);
            $parameters[] = $lookup[$bf_array['id']][1];
        }
    }
}

Then just append these conditions to your WHERE clause and feed the parameters array as the values for the ? placeholders.
